# Getting the result of the squared number in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

**Hi
i need to squared result of a variable (number) .
lets say i have a  that is equal to 77
can you use the multiple function register itself?

```
MOV AX,77
MUL AX,AX
MOV NUM,AX
```

if not, then what should i be doing the get the correct answer? thank you!**

Comment: read the manual for `mul`.

Comment: What architecture are you programming for?  If this is x86, what instructions are you allowed to use?  Just 8086 instructions?  Or are you allowed to use 80186 or 80386 instructions?

Comment: My bad for not adding, were only at the start TBH, we only learned about MUL DIV so far and were on the 8086

Comment: @Soske Then do as Peter Cordes said and refer to the manual.  It tells you how to use the `mul` instruction.  You should always look into the manual when you are unsure how to use an instruction.  If reading the manual leaves any questions, feel free to ask specific questions!

Comment: I didnt even know a manual existed! thank you guys very much!

Comment: @Soske Ah, I see.  That happens.  A good reference to use is this one: https://c9x.me/x86/.  It's a bit older so it doesn't have a lot of the confusing modern stuff you don't need anyway.